# Apply custom class to last element of an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to give separate width to the last div of ng-repeat,based on a certain condition. It's something like if a is greater than b i want class-a to be applied to the last div-

```
<div ng-repeat="variable in variables" ng-class="{(a>b)?'class-a':'class-b':$last}">
       <span> element</span>
</div>
```

But it doesnot work. Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to do with CSS using the :last-child property?

Comment: `ng-class="'{'class-a': (a > b) && $last, 'class-b': (a <= b) && $last}"`

Comment: Or `ng-class="a > b && $last ? 'class-a' : ($last ? 'class-b' : '')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understood correctly, you want to change the style of **last div** if `a > b`. 
You can try with something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in data" ng-class="[{'blue':((a > b) && $last)},{'red':((a < b) && $last)}]">
      {{value}}
</div>
```

Please check [complete example.](http://codepen.io/Hosar/pen/NpXoBq) 
hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

The class comes first and then the expression to evaluate.

Taken from the [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) documentation:

```
<ANY class="ng-class: expression;"> ... </ANY>
```

So in your case:

```
<div ng-repeat="variable in variables" ng-class="{'class-a': a > b && $last}">
    <span> element</span>
</div>
```

The above will add `class-a` on the div if a is greater than b and it's the last in ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="variable in variables" ng-class="{'class-a': a > b, 'class-b': $last}">
    <span> element</span>
</div>
```

The above will add `class-a` to the div if a is greater than b, and it will add `class-b` to the div if it's the last in ng-repeat.